# Incorrect redirections due to different locations

Tags: php, html

I have the file "menu.php" contain:

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a><br />
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

In each file I type:

```
<?php
include("menu.php");
?>
```

And it is working fine.

But now.. I created a folder called "data" and in it I created a file called "index.php" ...

In the index.php I typed:

```
<?php
include("../menu.php");
?>
```

So now the menu is displayed in "data/index.php" too , but ... while browsing "data/index.php" the links are:

Home: data/index.php
Logout: data/logout.php

How to make it index.php and logout.php without data/ ?

Comment: Possible solution is to prepend your urls in the html with a slash so it looks like `<a href="/index.php">...`. This will make the browser always go to the root directory.

Comment: @JensV - Now it redirect to the main root directory of the domain ... While menu.php is not in the root directory.

Comment: If your files are not located in the root of the webserver you should consider having absolute paths everywhere. E.g. `/dir/of/your/files/index.php`  
Also to achive this in php you can prepend your paths with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: if `index.php` is in folder data, then in `menu.php` , you should be giving `<a href="data/index.php">Home</a><br />` rght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead

```
<a href="/index.php">Home</a><br />
<a href="/logout.php">Logout</a>
```

or if you are using a sub folder

```
<a href="/subfolder/index.php">Home</a><br />
<a href="/subfolder/logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Now it redirect to the main root directory of the domain ... While menu.php is not in the root directory.

Comment: @Jacksweet are you using a sub folder ?

Comment: @Jacksweet Mehdi's answer is good. Use the subfolder option for your menu.php.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid *subfolder hades* and links is to declare a

> `<base href="/">`

at the top of your html.  then all links will be relative to the document root.  so the menu.php can function (at all subfolder levels) as if each page is truly at the document root level.

i might be able to whip up some code as an example if this interests you.  one great reason to go this direction would be to prevent from having to change a lot of other code.  one bad reason to go this way is if you already have a lot of code trying to overcome the subfolder crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PHP file to store the path of the sub folder or other variables that will be used throughout the website.

variables.php

```
    $path = '/subfolder/';
```

menu.php

```
     include('variables.php');
     global $path;

   <a href="<php echo $path ?>index.php">Home</a><br />
   <a href="<php echo $path ?>logout.php">Logout</a>
```